# Laravel 4 - Hardcoded authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I want to create authentication mechanism **without need for database** where only one person (admin) who knows right username and password (which I would hardcode) would be able to login. I still want to use Auth::attempt(), Auth::check() and other functions.

I found out that I could create my own [User driver](http://www.karlvalentin.de/1903/write-your-own-auth-driver-for-laravel-4.html), but it seems to me that there should be something simpler.

Maybe it is not very nice solution, but I want as simple as possible website.

Comment: As simple as possible means you can simply extend `attempt` and `check` methods and implement a simple comparator function which just check a request input for correct combination of user + pass.

Answer (score 5):

It may only seem there should be something simpler, but in fact that's as simple as you can get if you want to extend the authentication system. All the methods you're using through the `Auth` facade (like `attempt`, `check`, etc.), are implemented within the `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` class. This class needs a `UserProviderInterface` implementation to be injected into the constructor in order to work. Which means that in order to use the `Auth` facade you either need to use the already implemented `DatabaseUserProvider` or `EloquentUserProvider`, or implement your own provider that handles the simple login you want.

Although the article you linked to may look lengthy, to achieve what you need you might get away with much less code in the provider than you might think. Here's what I think is what you need:

**1.** In your `app/config/auth.php` change the driver to `simple` and append the desired login credentials:

```php
'driver' => 'simple',
'credentials' => array(
    'email'    => 'user@email.com',
    'password' => 'yourpassword'
)
```

**2.** Create a file in your `app` directory called `SimpleUserProvider.php` that has this code:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface;

class SimpleUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(array $credentials)
    {
        $this->user = new GenericUser(array_merge($credentials, array('id' => null)));
    }

    // If you only need to login via credentials the following 3 methods
    // don't need to be implemented, they just need to be defined
    public function retrieveById($identifier) { }
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) { }
    public function updateRememberToken(UserInterface $user, $token) { }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
    {
        return $credentials['email'] == $user->email && $credentials['password'] == $user->password;
    }

}
```

**3.** Lastly you'll need to register the new provider with the authentication system. You can append this to the `app/start/global.php` file:

```php
Auth::extend('simple', function($app)
{
    return new SimpleUserProvider($app['config']['auth.credentials']);
});
```

This should give you a simple (no database) user authentication while still being able to use Laravel's facades.

Comment: Thank you, it worked (almost :)). I just had to add this 
   `app_path() . '/components',` to `ClassLoader::addDirectories` and I put `SimpleUserProvider` to `app/components` directory.

Comment: Actually, I am able to pass `Auth::attemp`, but `Auth::check` always return `false`, i.e. I am always guest. Here is my code snippet: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zsq70KwK)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Every time I logged in, the login was successful but when on the `/home` page, I was redirected to the login page again.

I found out that this was due to the user not being stored in the session as authenticated user. To fix this, I had to implement the `getAuthIdentifier` method in the `User` model class and also implement the `retrieveById` method .

I've also adjusted my solution to support multiple hard coded users (it presumes, that the email is unique, so we can also use it as id for the user):

**1.** In `app/config/auth.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'array',
    ],
],

'credentials' => [
    'userA@email.com' => 'passA',
    'userB@email.com' => 'passB',
]
```

**2.** The `UserProvider`:

```
use \Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class ArrayUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    private $credential_store;

    public function __construct(array $credentials_array)
    {
        $this->credential_store = $credentials_array;
    }

    // IMPORTANT: Also implement this method!
    public function retrieveById($identifier) {
        $username = $identifier;
        $password = $this->credential_store[$username];
        return new User([
            'email' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        ]);
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) { }
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token) { }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        $username = $credentials['email'];

        // Check if user even exists
        if (!isset($this->credential_store[$username])) {
            return null;
        }

        $password = $this->credential_store[$username];
        return new GenericUser([
            'email' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'id' => null,
        ]);
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        return $credentials['email'] == $user->email && $credentials['password'] == $user->getAuthPassword();
    }
}
```

**3.** And in `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
...

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::provider('array', function($app, array $config) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...
            return new ArrayUserProvider($app['config']['auth.credentials']);
        });
    }
}
```

**4.** In User.php (model):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

### More Information:

For everyone who is interested, why there need to be the above stated additions:
When you login, the method `login` in `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` is called. In this method you will find, that the identifier of the user is stored in the session with `$this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier())`. Therefore we need to implement this method in our user model.

When you add `$this->middleware('auth')` in your controller, then the method `authenticate()` in `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` is called. This again calls `$this->auth->guard($guard)->check()` to check, whether a user is authenticated. The `check()` method only tests, that there exists a user in the session (see `Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers`). It does this by calling the `user()` method of the guard, which in this case is again `SessionGuard`. In the `user()` method, the user is retrieved by taking the id stored in the session and calling `retrieveById` to get the user.